# How to read and write 24-bit wav file using scipy or common alternative?

Tags: python, audio, numpy, scipy, wav

Frequently, wav files are or need to be 24-bit yet I do not see a way to write or read 24-bit wav files using scipy module. The documentation for wavfile.write() states that the resolution of the wav file is determined by the data type. That must mean 24-bit is not supported since I do not know of a 24-bit integer data type. If an alternative is necessary it would be nice if it were common so that files can be easily exchanged without the need for others with scipy to install additional module.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile

fs=48000
t=1
nc=2
nbits=24
x = np.random.rand(t*fs,nc) * 2 - 1
wavfile.write('white.wav', fs, (x*(2**(nbits-1)-1)).astype(np.int32))
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779416/faster-way-to-convert-from-24-bit-wav-pcm-format-to-float - one of the answers mentions scikits.audiolab which does have support for 24bit audio. However, in looking at the wav module I think it should work, although it might print a warning that it's an 'unknown' bitdepth. Python 'ints' are C-longs by default, and floats are C-doubles. But sounds like someone's already solved the problem.

Comment: In case you didn't see it already, there is a scipy issue for this, https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1930, but I don't know if anyone is working on adding this feature.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Looks like the ticket was made in 2011. Probably not going to be fixed anytime soon.

Comment: I know you asked this before I did, but I didn't see your question before asking my own! Anyway, the solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16767558/188535).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767248/how-do-i-write-a-24-bit-wav-file-in-python

Answer (score 5):

This is very easy using [PySoundFile](http://pysoundfile.readthedocs.org/):

```
import soundfile as sf

x = ...
fs = ...

sf.write('white.wav', x, fs, subtype='PCM_24')
```

The conversion from floating point to PCM is done automatically.

See also [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32348261/500098).

---

UPDATE:

In PySoundFile version 0.8.0, the argument order of `sf.write()` was changed.
Now the file name comes first, and the data array is the second argument. I've changed this in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

I have came across this problem as well. I have a buffer containing all the 32-bit signed samples, while in each sample, only 24 bits are used (highest 8 bits are 0 padding, even if the number is negative). My solution is:

```
    samples_4byte = self.buffer.tobytes()
    byte_format = ('%ds %dx ' % (3, 1)) * self.sample_len * 2
    samples_3byte = b''.join(struct.unpack(byte_format, samples_4byte))
```

Now I have a bytearray that can be written into the wave file:

```
with wave.open(file_abs, 'wb') as wav_file:
        # Set the number of channels
        wav_file.setnchannels(2)
        # Set the sample width to 3 bytes
        wav_file.setsampwidth(3)
        # Set the frame rate to sample_rate
        wav_file.setframerate(self.sample_rate)
        # Set the number of frames to sample_len
        wav_file.setnframes(self.sample_len)
        # Set the compression type and description
        wav_file.setcomptype('NONE', "not compressed")
        # Write data
        wav_file.writeframes(samples_3byte)
```