# How do I write a 24-bit WAV file in Python?

Tags: python, wav

I want to generate a 24-bit WAV-format audio file using Python 2.7 from an array of floating point values between -1 and 1. I can't use [scipy.io.wavfile.write](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html) because it only supports 16 or 32 bits. The documentation for Python's own [wave](http://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html) module doesn't specify what format of data it takes.

So is it possible to do this in Python?

Comment: 9 years later, there still seems to be no out-of-the-box way of doing this in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is available in [`wavio`](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/wavio) (also on PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wavio), a small module I created as a work-around to the problem of scipy not yet supporting 24 bit WAV files.  The file [`wavio.py`](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/wavio/blob/master/wavio.py) contains the function `write`, which writes a numpy array to a WAV file.  To write a 24-bit file, use the argument `sampwidth=3`.  The only dependency of `wavio` is numpy; `wavio` uses the standard library `wave` to deal with the WAV file format.

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import wavio
rate = 22050             # samples per second
T = 3                    # sample duration (seconds)
f = 440.0                # sound frequency (Hz)
t = np.linspace(0, T, T*rate, endpoint=False)
sig = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * t)
wavio.write("sine24.wav", sig, rate, sampwidth=3)
```

Answer (score 7):

I already [submitted an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17443437/500098) 2 years ago, where I recommended [scikits.audiolab](http://scikits.appspot.com/audiolab).

In the meantime, the situation has changed and now there is a library available which is much easier to use and much easier to install, it even comes with its own copy of the [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) library for Windows and OSX (on Linux it's easy to install anyway): [PySoundFile](http://pysoundfile.readthedocs.org/)!

If you have CFFI and NumPy installed, you can install PySoundFile simply by running

```
pip install soundfile --user
```

Writing a 24-bit WAV file is easy:

```
import soundfile as sf
sf.write('my_24bit_file.wav', my_audio_data, 44100, 'PCM_24')
```

In this example, `my_audio_data` has to be a NumPy array with `dtype` `'float64'`, `'float32'`, `'int32'` or `'int16'`.

BTW, I made an [overview page](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/audio-files/index.ipynb) where I tried to compare many available Python libraries for reading/writing sound files.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `wave` module, the `Wave_write.writeframes` function expects WAV data to be packed into a 3-byte string in little-endian format. The following code does the trick:

```
import wave
from contextlib import closing
import struct

def wavwrite_24(fname, fs, data):
    data_as_bytes = (struct.pack('<i', int(samp*(2**23-1))) for samp in data)
    with closing(wave.open(fname, 'wb')) as wavwriter:
        wavwriter.setnchannels(1)
        wavwriter.setsampwidth(3)
        wavwriter.setframerate(fs)
        for data_bytes in data_as_bytes:
            wavwriter.writeframes(data_bytes[0:3])
```

Comment: I think your scaling should be `(2**23-1)` or your samples will sign flip when `samp == 1.0`

Comment: Hmm, tricky. It's an inherent problem in fixed point — -1 can be represented, but +1 can't. Scaling by `2**23-1` means -1 maps to `-2**23+1`, which is wrong... but probably less wrong than flipping sign. (Clipping at `2**23-1` would be better, but I think it might add a lot of code.)

Comment: In my experience, it's fairly standard practice to just scale. Technically, every value is also being floored. The `ideal` conversion to integer would include rounding as well.

Comment: @paphabla The values aren't floored, but truncated, so `int(1.2)` is 1 but `int(-1.2)` is -1 *not* -2 (as `int(floor(-1.2))` would return)

Comment: 1. Doing the writing loop in Python will be very very slow, so it is not a solution for production programs: use `scipy` or `pysoundfile`.

2. `2**23-1` is better as a constant `0x7F_FFFF`

Comment: @TomSwirly I don't do DSP work any more, but it still seems like Scipy doesn't support writing 24-bit wav files. I can't speak on pysoundfile, I never tried to install or use it.

Comment: Good catch! `soundfile` (its new name) definitely promises to write 24-bit audio - e.g. https://github.com/bastibe/python-soundfile/blob/master/soundfile.py#L70 - and I'll know this week if this is actually true.

Answer (score 3):

Try the `wave` module:

```
In [1]: import wave

In [2]: w = wave.open('foo.wav', 'w') # open for writing

In [3]: w.setsampwidth(3) # 3 bytes/sample
```

Python can only pack integers in 2 and 4 bite sizes. So you can use a numpy array with a dtype on int32, and use a list comprehension to get 3/4 of the bytes of each integer:

```
In [14]: d = np.array([1,2,3,4], dtype=np.int32)

In [15]: d
Out[15]: array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32)

In [16]: [d.data[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(d)*d.dtype.itemsize, d.dtype.itemsize)]
Out[16]: ['\x01\x00\x00', '\x02\x00\x00', '\x03\x00\x00', '\x04\x00\x00']
```

Comment: What should I give to the `writeframes` function?

Comment: @detly: if you start with a numpy array of `int32` type, you can just take the bytes you need, see above.

Comment: The question is about how to write the frames, yet no writeframes examples.

Answer (score 2):

You should try [scikits.audiolab](http://scikits.appspot.com/audiolab):

```
import numpy as np
from scikits.audiolab import Sndfile, Format

sig = np.array([0, 1, 0, -1, 0], dtype=np.float32)
f = Sndfile('test_pcm24.wav', 'w', Format('wav', 'pcm24'), 1, 44100)
f.write_frames(sig)
f.close()  # use contextlib.closing in real code
```

And to read it again:

```
f = Sndfile('test_pcm24.wav')
sig = f.read_frames(f.nframes, dtype=np.float32)
f.close()  # use contextlib.closing in real code
```

`scikits.audiolab` uses [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/), so in addition to WAV files, you can also use FLAC, OGG and some more file formats.

Comment: Note that there is currently (audiolab version 0.11.0) a bug in `read_frames()` when specifying another type than `float64`: https://github.com/cournape/audiolab/issues/3

Comment: I only just discovered how truly awful it is to try to install this on Windows. Changing answer to `wavio`.

Comment: @detly I created [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32348261/500098) suggesting [PySoundFile](http://pysoundfile.readthedocs.org/). What do you think about that?

Comment: I'll give it a shot! Sorry, I wasn't having a go at *you*, I just had two days of frustration and dependency hell.

Comment: No problem, I'm not affiliated with `audiolab`, feel free to complain about it as much as you want! OTOH, I *am* a collaborator on PySoundFile, where we tried to make the installation process as convenient as possible. If there is still reason to complain, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of `scipy.io.wavfile` that adds:

- 24 bit .wav files support for read/write,
- access to cue markers,
- cue marker labels,
- some other metadata like pitch (if defined), etc.

[wavfile.py (enhanced)](https://gist.github.com/josephernest/3f22c5ed5dabf1815f16efa8fa53d476)

Answer (score 0):

Make use of ffmpeg to interchange between wav codecs, below is a sample code

```
command = "ffmpeg -i input.wav -ar 22050 output.wav"
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16767558/1205590) from @detly works very well.

Calling `writeframes` once for each sample frame introduces huge overhead and makes the original solution very slow. Computing to an array and writing the data in a single call may yield better performance.

This is what i'm using:

```
import wave
from contextlib import closing
import struct
import numpy as np

INT24_FAC = (2**23)-1

def wavwrite_24(filename, fs, data):
    data_as_bytes = np.array(list(struct.pack('<i', x)[0:3] for x in (INT24_FAC * data).astype(int)))
    with closing(wave.open(filename, 'wb')) as wavwriter:
        wavwriter.setnchannels(1)
        wavwriter.setsampwidth(3)
        wavwriter.setframerate(fs)
        wavwriter.writeframes(data_as_bytes)
```

In my case the input data is an efficient numpy array if that makes any difference.