# Issues with wav file sample data ranges in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, wav

thanks for reading. I'm doing a little project with audio manipulation in Python with numpy/scipy. I'll say in advance that I'm not too familiar with audio stuff in real details. (The angle from which I'm approaching this are neural networks.)

Anyway, I'm using scipy.io.wavfile to read and write wav files into/from numpy arrays. My issue is with the datatype of the audio frames. I have to normalize the data to floating point numbers between -1 and 1 for my neural network stuff, and one issue I had at first was getting data back out of everything that ended up as a proper audio file. I had to cast all samples to int16 to get a proper waveform with the correct length back.

And that makes a lot of sense since my audio files have a bit depth of 16 bit.

Now however, I'm trying to do the same on different audio files, with 24 bit depth, and somehow after reading it with

```
stream = sp.read(audiofile, False)
```

the resulting Stream has samples with way too many digits. I know that the maximum number an 24 bit integer can store is about 16 million. Instead I'm getting values in the billions. The array I'm getting from that function is of type int32. 
Moreover, I can't find a way to put these samples back into a valid wav file, not surprisingly. I only get silence, and the length is messed up and not what it was.

```
def convert_to_3D(sample, network, variance):
'''
Convert audio samples to virtual surround
'''
dtype = sample.dtype
sample = sample.astype(float)
# Normalize
sample = (sample/variance)
# Transform
resultStream = network.insert_input(sample)  
# Denormalize
resultStream = resultStream * variance
resultStream = np.rint(resultStream)
resultStream = resultStream.astype(dtype) #("int16")
return resultStream

def convert_file(filename, network):
stream = u.read(filename)    
variance = np.var(stream)
print "Varianz: ", variance
print "Converting..."
for i in range(len(stream)):
    stream[i] = convert_to_3D(stream[i], network, variance)
filename = filename.rsplit( ".", 1 )[0] + "_3D.wav" 
u.write(stream, filename )
print "File ", filename, " has been written"
```

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Scipy doesn't support 24 bit wav files. I am guessing here, but probably each of your 32bit ints, has 3 bytes from one sample, and another one from the next. If your array is 3/4 of the length you are expecting, this is probably what's happening. It shouldn't bee too hard to extract your 24 bit values into 32 bit ints, but I am not sure you will be able to write anything in that same format. It appears to be possible with Python's `wave` module, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767248/how-do-i-write-a-24-bit-wav-file-in-python/16767558#16767558).

Comment: The length actually is 3/4, I should have noticed that. Thanks a ton, this cleared up the mystery. I suppose I have to look into using the wave module now.