# Recording 24-bit audio with pyaudio

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

I need to record 24-bit audio (because it's the archival standard for audio digitization). However, the wave library seems to only go up to 16-bit.

It looks like pyaudio can work with 24-bit audio but every example I've found shows pyaudio using the wave library, meaning it has to save 16-bit.

Is it possible to record and playback 24-bit audio with pyaudio?

Comment: If you're not obligated to use `pyaudio`, you might want to check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767248/how-do-i-write-a-24-bit-wav-file-in-python

Comment: I want to use pyaudio because it has some nice features which make visualization possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You just have to take the [record example](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#examples) of PyAudio and replace `pyaudio.paInt16` by `pyaudio.paInt24`.

```
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt24
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

Comment: This works, I wonder if it's possible to double check that this is truely 24-bit and not a 24-bit recording, downconverted into 16-bit and thens saved as a 24 bit file.

Answer (score -1):

check if the top end 8 bits are 0. If they are not, you have a true 24 bit recording.