# SciPy wavfile: music in, garbage out?

Tags: python, audio, scipy

I have isolated my problem to what seems to be the bare minimum: reading a WAV file in, and immediately writing it back out.  The output is noise, despite the input being music.  This puzzles me.  Here's the code:

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile
rate, data = wavfile.read("myinput.wav")
wavfile.write("myoutput.wav", rate, data)
```

Presumably I'm doing something very stupid. Could someone please tell me how to get this to work?

P.S. Adding a "print data" between reading in and writing out produces...

```
[ 889195140  456589342  2605824 ...,  221785355 1292756287  873860659]
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. My input and output WAV files have the exact same MD5 hash. Can you upload your input file somewhere?

Comment: Which version of scipy are you using?  How many bits per sample is the data in the wav file?  Can you post the file somewhere?

Comment: Sure, here's a link to the file:    [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/krz2wvf6mgvs5fy/theocean_left.wav) It's the left channel (mono) of an MP3 of a short Zeppelin clip.   I'm using Python 2.7.5 and SciPy 0.13.0 -- both from MacPorts, on OS X 10.8.5.        After reading your comments, I tried some other files and found that some of them would work, and others wouldn't.  Not sure what the determining factor is.  All were exported via Audacity at either 48 kHz or 44.1 kHz, with metadata left blank.

Comment: That file reports 24 bits per sample, which doesn't work; the code apparently only supports sizes for which there is an integer type (8, 16, 32, 64 bits). Also, I get an exception `ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size` when reading for the file you linked. Do you get an exception, or does it pass silently?

Answer (score 2):

With some additional conversion you can use 24-bit WAV files with the `wave` module from the standard library.

```
import wave
import numpy as np
from contextlib import closing

def pcm24to32(data, nchannels=1):
    temp = np.zeros((len(data) / 3, 4), dtype='b')
    temp[:, 1:] = np.frombuffer(data, dtype='b').reshape(-1, 3)
    return temp.view('<i4').reshape(-1, nchannels)

def pcm2float(sig, dtype=np.float64):
    sig = np.asarray(sig)  # make sure it's a NumPy array
    assert sig.dtype.kind == 'i', "'sig' must be an array of signed integers!"
    dtype = np.dtype(dtype)  # allow string input (e.g. 'f')

    # Note that 'min' has a greater (by 1) absolute value than 'max'!
    # Therefore, we use 'min' here to avoid clipping.
    return sig.astype(dtype) / dtype.type(-np.iinfo(sig.dtype).min)

with closing(wave.open('my_24bit_input.wav')) as w:
    framerate = w.getframerate()
    nframes = w.getnframes()
    nchannels = w.getnchannels()
    width = w.getsampwidth()
    data = w.readframes(nframes)

assert width == 3

pcm = pcm24to32(data, nchannels)

# You can also use np.float64, if you prefer:
normalized = pcm2float(pcm, np.float32)
```

I created an [IPython notebook with some more information](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/mgeier/python-audio/master/audio-files/audio-files-with-wave.ipynb).

Of course, you could also use `scikits.audiolab`, but be aware there is currently (version 0.11.0) a bug (https://github.com/cournape/audiolab/issues/3) when using types other than `np.float64`!

You could also try https://github.com/bastibe/PySoundFile, but I didn't try it myself (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the many helpful comments.

I was not aware of the 24 bit issue, but searching around I see many threads and proposed fixes related to this issue.  For me, I'll use to use scikits.audiolab in the manner described by user LMO in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779416/faster-way-to-convert-from-24-bit-wav-pcm-format-to-float), which I got working with Python 2.7 on my Mac via MacPorts and easy_install.

```
sudo port install libsndfile; sudo easy_install-2.7 scikits.audiolab
```

Then final code uses audiolab for read in (could make it do the same for writing)...

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile
import numpy as np
from scikits.audiolab import Sndfile
f = Sndfile("myinput.wav", 'r')
data = np.array(f.read_frames(f.nframes), dtype=np.float64)
f.close()
rate = f.samplerate;
wavfile.write("myoutput.wav", rate, data)
```

This works on the file in question and many others.

Comment: If you have found a solution for your own answer, you can always accept this answer and thus show other users the correct solution.